# Show/Hide OR Toggle multiple elements with same class, only show one at a time on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Alright. So I'm going to try and explain this the best I can. I just don't understand how to use jQuery in HTML and a javascript answer would be most appreciated, but I'll take jQuery if you can give me HTML with it, and not just jQuery code.

I have a guide page, the guide page itself is embedded into the main page using php (index.php?content=guide). On the guide page, I would like to use a show/hide OR a toggle function of sorts to toggle certain parts of the page, as related to the guide. Then, I would like to only show one at a time, as one link is clicked, only show the clicked elements and hide the rest. The list is on the left hand side of the page, while the content to be shown is on the right.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/wesman2232/2m2jjcc9/`
```

(Why isn't toggle working on jsfiddle? It's working fine on my local webserver)

Normally I would just make a different php page for each and every subsection (index.php?content=guide&do=requirements) but I want to try and get away from that, so I'm trying to just get it in one whole page

Currently, it toggles like I want, but I would rather have it all in one script instead of having to write out something like show('news'); show('news2'); hide('updates'); hide('updates2'); etc etc. Also if you just kept clicking on Synopsis it would toggle between the two instead of just switching to that one, and that one only.

I get that this isn't multiple, but for the multiple part is where I have something like this on the media page:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/wesman2232/mwnua9q8/`
```

except I would change it from using id to class and set them all having the same class right?

Guess I need to go back and re-learn everything cause I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around all this haha. I've tried reading other questions but still can't get it to work the way I want it to.

Comment: in JSFIDDLE you need to specify the LOAD. Since you are placing onclick attributes, you need to set the option **_"No wrap in <head>"_**

Comment: Oh ok I see now, gotcha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code, in my opinion, is that it is outdated. You are using `tables` for non tabular design and you are making it difficult for yourself using pure JS in comparison to jQuery.

You need to do the following:

- do away with `tables` and use `divs`
- use the powerful ways of styling your content with CSS3
- even though it is very good to know plain JS, use jQuery to make coding fun and easy.
- always try to make your HTML as clean as possible with the use of IDs and Classes

This is the way I would redo your code:

```js
$(".link").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".content").removeClass("active");
     var content_id = $(this).attr("href");
     $(content_id).addClass("active");
 });
```

```css
#wrapper {
     text-align: center;
 }
 #content_container {
     margin-top: 10px;
 }
 .content:not(.active) {
     display: none;
 }
.title{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>
        <a class="link" href="#screenshots">Screenshots</a> | 
        <a class="link" href="#videos">Videos</a> | 
        <a class="link" href="#wallpaper">Wallpapers</a>
    </div>
    <div id="content_container">
        <div id="screenshots" class="content active">
            <div class="title">Screenshots</div>
            <div class="description">Screenshot description</div>
        </div>
        <div id="videos" class="content">
            <div class="title">Videos</div>
            <div class="description">Videos description</div>
        </div>
        <div id="wallpaper" class="content">
            <div class="title">Wallpapers</div>
            <div class="description">Wallpapers description</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Using tables may be outdated, but it's easier to organize information the way I want it to look than trying to figure out how and exactly where to put it with absolute, relative, fixed, etc positions. I also don't feel the need to add a class or id for every single element, like if I don't need to style the element at all. If I really needed to easily find information, or to organize it, I'd use comments. All in my opinion of course.

Your answer works flawlessly though, and I appreciate the advice to learn from. I'll continue with a question in the next comment.

Comment: What is the # used for in the anchor other than to specify part of the page? Better way to ask is how it relates to the jQuery code? Couldn't I also just use javascript:void(); to still switch the active content?

Comment: Glad you considered my advice, but as you say, its the developer's decision. To answer your question, the `#` is there to specify the ID we want to trigger. For example look at the second link, It has a class of `link` and an href of `#videos`. Now look at the JS code we attach a `click` event to all the elements with the class `link`, then we say when that element is clicked get its href as the id (`var content_id = $(this).attr("href");`) and use it to add a class to the element with that id `$(content_id).addClass("active");` thus, `<div id="videos" ` will now have a class of `active`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I actually reconsidered re-coding my website to use divs instead of tables. It actually shocked me how well it works. I don't have the problem of trying to fit rows and columns together to flow correctly, and other elements doesn't affect their positions now. Finding the correct positions to have them the way I want it is a little pain, but I now find it easier. Thank you. I accepted your answer for my question. Although, if I could, I would also accept DinoMyte's answer as well because he also gave an answer to the other part of my question. He gets half credit.

Comment: Also, how would I use this on dynamically generated content? I have my index page with my navigations calling the media page via PHP so that I can have a global navigation. I can't seem to get any jQuery to work in my pages. I've tried putting the script in the head, and on the media page itself. I've also made sure that I'm including the jQuery .js file to use it. Any advice or would you have to look at it?

Comment: I'd have to look at it. Maybe create another question and post your code so that I can inspect.

Comment: Sorry for the wait. I don't have internet access at home and I work 40 hours a week hehe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270199/follow-up-for-codegodie

Comment: Wow. I just got it to work by adding in the document ready function. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ah I see... Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
It's a jquery version.

```
    $().ready(function()
    {
   $('#gm, #pg').click(function()
{
    if($(this).attr("id") == "gm")
    {
        $("#gameinformation").toggle();
        if($("#playguide").is(":visible"))
        $("#playguide").toggle();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#playguide").toggle();
        if($("#gameinformation").is(":visible"))
        $("#gameinformation").toggle();
    }
});
    });
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2m2jjcc9/2/

ALTERNATE APPROACH :

If you multiple section to toggle, you may use the following. I used an approach to tag each corresponding 'UL' tags of 'a' with an attribute called 'data-dependency' and use it to toggle sections.

```
$('a').click(function()
{
    var $this = $(this).attr('id');
    $('a').each(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if(id == $this)
        {           
             $("ul[data-dependency='" + id + "']").toggle();           
        }
        else            
        {
           if($("ul[data-dependency='" + id + "']").is(":visible"))
           $("ul[data-dependency='" + id + "']").toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2m2jjcc9/4/

UPDATED BASED ON REQUIREMENT TO KEEP ALL MENUS OPTIONS OPEN :

```
$('a').click(function()
{    
    var $this = $(this).attr('id');
    if($("ul[data-dependency='" + $this + "']")[0] != undefined)
      $("ul[data-dependency='" + $this + "']").toggle();
    else
        $(this).closest('li').find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2m2jjcc9/5/

Comment: I'm going to be using a different toggle for each and every link. That might get a bit tedious with this. Giant wall of elseifs, but it would work if need be. Also, I'd rep you but I can't until I have 15 rep.

Comment: I've added an alt approach. Try it and see if it works.

Comment: I really like your alternate approach for the guide page. The only problem I have with it is that it toggles part of the navigations off when selecting another. Would I have to have a separate jQuery code for the navigation and the content? I'll explain like this, Start off with both menus closed. Then open up one at a time, which would keep both open if user chose to, then only switch the content area depending on navigation choice.

Really hate to ask for straight answers, I feel like a leecher that cant figure anything out myself.

Comment: i've updated the code to reflect the changes you require. It would also work on the sub menus.

Comment: You're awesome, friend. Unfortunately, I don't think I can pick an answer on this question. Seeing as you and CodeGodie both gave correct and working answers.

Comment: Actually, jsfiddle is saying your code isn't completely functional? Somewhere in line 4

Comment: Works fine for me ( using FF ) . Try on a different browser.

Comment: Using latest Beta channel FireFox as well. I'll download and install chrome though.

Comment: I accepted CodeGodie's answer as the answer for this question. Although if I could, I'd also accept yours as well, because you gave an answer to half of my question. You get half credit by me.